# Unable to Display captcha image in codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I am having a page with contact form which includes captcha in the page but i am unable to display the captcha image.How to display the captcha image in view.Here is my code

Controller:

```
public function contact_mail()
{
    $this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->model('index_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');        
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required');
    if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){

        if($this->input->post('submit')){
        $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
        $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
        if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha){
            echo 'Captcha code matched.';
        }else{
            echo 'Captcha code was not match, please try again.';
        }
    }
        // Captcha configuration
    $config = array(
        'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha_images/',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => 50,
        'word_length'   => 8,
        'font_size'     => 16
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);

    // Unset previous captcha and store new captcha word
    $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

    // Send captcha image to view
        $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
        $data['mainpage'] = "contact";
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
    }
    else{
        $result=$this->index_model->send_mail($this->input->post('email'));
        if($result)
        {
            $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:green">Thank You! Your  Message has been sent</h2>');
            redirect('contact');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Sorry ! Message sending failed</h2>');
            redirect('contact');
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="">

                        <div class="contactcaptcha">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha_image" placeholder="captcha_image" style="background-color: #f4f4f4;border: none;" required>
                            <?php echo form_error('captcha_image', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Updated my code

Comment: Anyone can sort these

Comment: why you create captcha after form validation. you have to create in function at where you load your view.

Comment: @Nidhi where i need to create function and for which functionality i need to create a function

Comment: check below. i post my code...

Answer (score 0):

Are you resuming session?

> session_start() — Start new or resume existing session

take a look on this:

**Controller**

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Captcha_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    // Load Helper in and Start session.
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        session_start();
    }
    // This function show values in view page and check captcha value.
    public function form()
    {
        if (empty($_POST)) {
            $this->captcha_setting();
        } else {
            // Case comparing values.
            if (strcasecmp($_SESSION['captchaWord'], $_POST['captcha']) == 0) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Your form successfully submitted'); </script>";
                $this->captcha_setting();
            } else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Try Again'); </script>";
                $this->captcha_setting();
            }
        }
    }
    // This function generates CAPTCHA image and store in "image folder".
    public function captcha_setting()
    {
        $values                  = array(
            'word' => '',
            'word_length' => 8,
            'img_path' => './images/',
            'img_url' => base_url() . 'images/',
            'font_path' => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width' => '150',
            'img_height' => 50,
            'expiration' => 3600
        );
        $data                    = create_captcha($values);
        $_SESSION['captchaWord'] = $data['word'];

        // image will store in "$data['image']" index and its send on view page
        $this->load->view('captcha_view', $data);
    }
    // For new image on click refresh button.
    public function captcha_refresh()
    {
        $values                  = array(
            'word' => '',
            'word_length' => 8,
            'img_path' => './images/',
            'img_url' => base_url() . 'images/',
            'font_path' => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width' => '150',
            'img_height' => 50,
            'expiration' => 3600
        );
        $data                    = create_captcha($values);
        $_SESSION['captchaWord'] = $data['word'];
        echo $data['image'];

    }
}
?>
```

**View**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add captcha using CodeIgniter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Raleway' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Ajax post for refresh captcha image.
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.refresh").click(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/captcha_controller/captcha_refresh",
            success: function(res) {
            if (res)
            {
            jQuery("div.image").html(res);
            }
            }
            });
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div id="content">
                <h2 id="form_head">Captcha Using Codelgniter</h2>
                <br/>
                <hr>
                <div id="form_input">
                    <?php
                        // Form Open
                        echo form_open();

                        // Name Field
                        echo form_label('Name');
                        $data_name = array(
                        'name' => 'name',
                        'class' => 'input_box',
                        'placeholder' => 'Please Enter Name',
                        'id' => 'name',
                        'required' => ''
                        );
                        echo form_input($data_name);
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";

                        // Email Field
                        echo form_label('Email');
                        $data_email = array(
                        'name' => 'email',
                        'class' => 'input_box',
                        'placeholder' => 'Please Enter Email',
                        'id' => 'email',
                        'required' => ''
                        );
                        echo form_input($data_email);
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";

                        echo "<div class='image'>";

                        // $image is the index of $data array. which will send by controller.
                        echo $image;
                        echo "</div>";

                        // Calling for refresh captcha image.
                        echo "<a href='#' class ='refresh'><img id = 'ref_symbol' src =".base_url()."img/refresh.png></a>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "<br>";

                        // Captcha word field.
                        echo form_label('Captcha');
                        $data_captcha = array(
                        'name' => 'captcha',
                        'class' => 'input_box',
                        'color' => 'white',
                        'placeholder' => '',
                        'id' => 'captcha'
                        );
                        echo form_input($data_captcha);
                        ?>
                </div>
                <div id="form_button">
                    <?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit', "class='submit'"); ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                    // Form Close
                    echo form_close(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
.main
{
width: 1015px;
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left: 20%;
}
#form_head
{
text-align: center;
background-color: #FEFFED;
height: 66px;
margin: 0 0 -29px 0;
padding-top: 35px;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
color: rgb(97, 94, 94);
}
#content {
position: absolute;
width: 450px;
height: 490px;
border: 2px solid gray;
border-radius: 10px;
}
#content_result{
position: absolute;
width: 450px;
height: 192px;
border: 2px solid gray;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-left: 559px;
margin-top: -262px;
}
#form_input
{
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 36px;
}
label
{
margin-right: 6px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#form_button{
padding: 0 21px 15px 15px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
width: 414px;
background-color: #FEFFED;
border-radius: 0px 0px 8px 8px;
border-top: 1px solid #9A9A9A;
}
.submit{
font-size: 16px;
background: linear-gradient(#ffbc00 5%, #ffdd7f 100%);
border: 1px solid #e5a900;
color: #4E4D4B;
font-weight: bold;
cursor: pointer;
width: 300px;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px 0;
outline: none;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 15%;
}
.submit:hover{
background: linear-gradient(#ffdd7f 5%, #ffbc00 100%);
}
.label_output
{
color:#4A85AB;
margin-left: 10px;
}
#result_id
{
text-align: center;
background-color: #FCD6F4;
height: 47px;
margin: 0 0 -29px 0;
padding-top: 12px;
border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
color: rgb(97, 94, 94);
}
#result_show
{
margin-top: 35px;
margin-left: 45px;
}
.input_box{
height:40px;
width:240px;
padding:20px;
border-radius:3px;
background-color:#FEFFED;
margin-left:30px;
}
img {
margin-left: 97px;
}
input#name {
margin-left: 45px;
}
input#email {
margin-left: 50px;
}
img#ref_symbol {
margin-left: 275px;
margin-top: -36px;
}
```

**Result**
[image: captcha]

Comment: Can you tell me what was the issue in my code which i have done

Comment: I am not saying that there is issue in your code i am asking what was the issue in my code so that i know right where  i am making mistake

Answer (score 0):

Generate captcha in codeigniter

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
    $this->load->model('index_model');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

        if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                echo "please enter captcha";
            } else {
                $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
                $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
                if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha){
                    echo 'Captcha code matched.';
                        $result=$this->index_model->send_mail($this->input->post('email'));
                        //$result = 1;
                        if($result)
                        {
                            $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:green">Thank You! Your  Message has been sent</h2>');
                            redirect('contact');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Sorry ! Message sending failed</h2>');
                            redirect('contact');
                        }
                }else{
                    echo 'Captcha code was not match, please try again.';
                }

            }
        }
        // Captcha configuration
    $config = array(
        'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
        'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha_images/',
        'img_width'     => '150',
        'img_height'    => 50,
        'word_length'   => 8,
        'font_size'     => 16
    );
    $captcha = create_captcha($config);

    // Unset previous captcha and store new captcha word
    $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
    $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

    // Send captcha image to view
        $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
        $data['mainpage'] = "contact";
        // print_r($data);
        $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
```

Display captcha in view page

```
<p id="captImg"><?php echo $captchaImg; ?></p>
```

Comment: Not able to display the captcha code which should be entered in the textbox

Comment: `<p id="captImg"><?php echo $captchaImg; ?></p> ` add this line in view

Comment: check **captcha_images** this folder captcha images generated there or not?

Comment: where this folder should be created

Comment: comment this `if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){` condition . again you are wrong....

Comment: create **captcha_images** folder at where 'application' folder and 'index.php'  is.

Comment: index.php file is in application/views folder so where i need to create this folder

Comment: at project root, where 'application' and 'system' folder is

Comment: Created captcha_images folder but no captcha images are generated

Comment: You said that i am doing wrong can you edit on my edit where i did wrong

Comment: It is displaying blank page

Comment: changed the code according to the one which you send but the page is blank not displaying anything

Comment: ANy idea y it is not displaying

Comment: sorry, i can't help you much more. Generating captcha is not big deal in codeigniter. and do not add or edit your code just copy paste my code.its working.

Comment: Still it is displaying the same error as undefined variable captchaImg

Comment: Changed the file permissions as well but getting the same error only

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with this code:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Captcha_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    // Load Helper in and Start session.
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        session_start();      
    }
    // This function show values in view page and check capcha value.
    public function contact_mail() {
        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        $this->load->model('index_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){

            if($this->input->post('submit')){
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
            if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha){
                echo 'Captcha code matched.';
            }else{
                echo 'Captcha code was not match, please try again.';
            }
        }
            // Captcha configuration
        $config = array(
            'word' => 'word',
            'word_length' => 8,
            'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha_images/',
            'font_path'  => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '150',
            'img_height'    => 50,
            'word_length'   => 8,
            'font_size'     => 16
        );

        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        // Unset previous captcha and store new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

        // Send captcha image to view
            $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];
            $data['mainpage'] = "contact";
            $this->load->view('captcha_view',$data);
        }
        else{
             $result=$this->index_model->send_mail($this->input->post('email'));
            if($result)
            {
                $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:green">Thank You! Your  Message has been sent</h2>');
            redirect('contact');
            }
            else
            {
                $this->flash->success('<h2 style="color:red">Sorry ! Message sending failed</h2>');
            redirect('contact');
            }
        }
      }
      // This function genrate CAPTCHA image and store in "image folder".
    public function captcha_setting(){
                $values = array(
                'word' => 'word',
                'word_length' => 8,
                'img_path' => './images/',
                'img_url' =>  base_url() .'images/',
                'font_path'  => base_url() . 'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
                'img_width' => '150',
                'img_height' => 50,
                'expiration' => 3600
               );
            $data = create_captcha($values);
                  $_SESSION['captchaWord'] = $data['word'];

                  // image will store in "$data['image']" index and its send on view page 
            $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
       }    
}
?>
```